# ZeroDivisionError when listing factors of a number

Tags: python, list

The program I am writing is tasked with creating a list of all possible factors of a number, excluding the number itself. My code is as follows:

```py
def list_all_factors(num):
    result = []
    for i in range(0, num):
        if num % i == 0:
            result.append(i)
    return result
```

When I call this function I get the following error:

```
ZeroDivisionError: integer division or modulo by zero
```

What is causing this issue, and how can I resolve it?

Comment: "integer division _or modulo_ by zero". What do you think happens in the very first iteration of this loop?

Comment: `for i in range(1, num)`

Comment: See how to create a [mcve]. Most of your code is irrelevant to the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because you are trying to divide by zero as the error says in the for loop. You should start the range from 1 to avoid it.

```
def list_all_factors(num):
    result = []
    for i in range(1, num+1):
        if num % i == 0:
            result.append(i)
    return result
```

or list comprehension

```
def list_all_factors(num):
    result = [i for i in range(1,num+1) if num % i == 0]
    return result
```

Answer (score 1):

The `for` loop:

```
for i in range(0, num)
```

should be

```
for i in range(1, num)
```

We change the lower bound to avoid attempting to divide by zero.